# pushing tar files to s3 using jenkins with Makefile

Tags: jenkins, makefile

I am trying to deploy build folder with jenkins, I am adding the Makefile in the source code which will push all my build files to s3 in a tar format.

Below is my Makefile, i am newbie to this Makefile.

So based on the jenkins build params, i am checking what should be the filename to be added and which script to be choosed.

Here i have written using if else, but don't know how to run this locally and check and is it correct.

also can i use switch instead of if else, so more env comes it will be helpful.

Whats the command for running this file from local, i tried `make -f Makefile`, but nothing happened just printed `command for checking testing`

```
run test: 
    # command for checking testing

create tar file:
    # pick the proper env based on jenkins params
    mkdir target

    if [${ENV} = "testing"]; then \
        npm install && npm run build:testing 
        tar czf target/app-${BUILD_NUMBER}_testing.tar.gz build/    
    else \
        npm install && npm run build:development
        tar czf target/app-${BUILD_NUMBER}_development.tar.gz build/    
    fi 
    
push to s3: 
     aws s3 sync target/ s3://app-builds
```

Basically i am trying to get the tar files in the app-builds bucket in s3, which will have the files inside the build folder when the command runs it, example based on env passed from jenkins params.

Expected output in s3 app-builds bucket

```
app-0.0.1_testing.tar.gz
app-0.0.2_testing.tar.gz
app-0.0.3_development.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

First - proposal: eliminate the space from the target name. Make does not work well with files/target with embedded space. For example: "push to s3" should be "push_to_s3" (or similar)

By default, invoking make will execute the first target in the makefile (run test). To invoke the s3 target, use "make push_to_s3".

Comment: Thanks for the response, When i tried to run it, i am getting this mkdir: target: File exists. I used this command to run it => make create_tar_file ENV=testing

Comment: can you correct  the places where i am doing wrong in the Makefile and post it, also what's the command for running from start, that won't pause at the run-test, it should continue. Any help on this

Comment: when i given mkdir -p target, the issue gone , but now i am getting /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file